# Using strptime() to convert data into datetime object is giving various errors

Tags: python

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
06/22/20-14:57:52,0,18.1436
06/22/20-14:57:53,1,18.5368
.
.
.
```

I need to convert the date-time column into something readable and then convert it back for plotting purposes. For this, I am using datetime.datetime.strptime(). Here is my code:

```
def datestr2num(s):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s.decode('ascii'),'%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S')

ntc = np.loadtxt('path/to/file/ntc_readings.txt', delimiter=',', converters={0:datestr2num})
print(ntc) #check
```

Python should be able to distinguish the columns, I believe, as it's in an appropriate format, but if I don't include the delimiter to tell it to ignore the commas, I get `ValueError: unconverted data remains: ,0,18.1436`. Of course, I only want to convert the first column of data, which is why I have `converters={0:datestr2num}`. This makes me think that it's not reading the data as three columns without the delimiter, and instead a single column, which is odd.

When I do include `delimiter=','`, I get `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`. I have no idea why, when I include the delimiter, loadtxt doesn't like my usage of datetime.datetime.

I have tried time.strptime(), to which I get the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` I wonder if this has to do with using decode(), but if I don't use it, `'%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S` doesn't work, even though it is the correct format of my date-time data.

Any thoughts as to what the problem is?

Comment: I think if you're going to specify `converters` then you should specify every column *or* specify a generic processor. That would suggest updating your `datestr2num()` to also strip off the `,.*$`. I would use something like `datetime.datetime.strptime(s.split(",")[0].decode("UTF-8"),....)` in your function

Comment: ... as well as `converters=datestr2num` in your `np.loadtxt()` call

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This makes sense, though when I try it, it doesn't like how I'm using the converters parameter because I get an error `'function' object has no attribute 'items'`. I think I need to give it

Comment: I just checked the docstr for `np.loadtxt()` and the converters param does have to be a dict, which means you would have to know how many columns you have at the start. It might be better to just use
`   with open("myfile", "r").readlines() as input:
      times = datestr2num(input.split(",")[0].decode("UTF-8"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `datestr2num` is expected to return number, but it is returning datetime instead.

You can modify it as follow:

```
def datestr2num(s):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s.decode('ascii'),'%m/%d/%y-%H:%M:%S')
    return date.utcnow().timestamp()
```

Alternatively you can use a module called pandas.
You can use it as follow:

```
import pandas as pd

ntc = pd.read_csv('path/to/file/ntc_readings.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't use pandas as I'm on a remote computer and don't have the ability to install libraries, but I tried your first modification and am no longer getting errors. I'm getting a single number for all the date-time readings, but I wonder if once I convert them back they'll be correct. I will see.